# Rename Powerpoint objects with text box content macro

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I found a macro that automatically renames the objects, however, I need to tweak it so it displays part of the content of the actual text box/shape. Does anyone know how this can be done?
The macro I found is this one:

```
Option Explicit

' ============================================================
' PowerPoint Macro : RenameOnSlideObjects
' ============================================================
' Purpose : Renames all on-slide objects within a presentation
' Inputs : Noe
' Outputs : None
' Dependencies : None
' Author : Jamie Garroch of http://youpresent.co.uk/
' Date : 01 December 2015
' ============================================================
Public Sub RenameOnSlideObjects()
  Dim oSld As Slide
  Dim oShp As Shape
  For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
      With oShp
        Select Case True
          Case .Type = msoPlaceholder ' you could then check the placeholder type too
            .Name = "test"
          Case .Type = msoTextBox
            .Name = "myTextBox"
          Case .Type = msoAutoShape
            .Name = "myShape"
          Case .Type = msoChart
            .Name = "myChart"
          Case .Type = msoTable
            .Name = "myTable"
          Case .Type = msoPicture
            .Name = "myPicture"
          Case .Type = msoSmartArt
            .Name = "mySmartArt"
          Case .Type = msoGroup ' you could then cycle though each shape in the group
            .Name = "myGroup"
         Case Else
            .Name = "Unspecified Object"
        End Select
      End With
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

So, for example, I would like "Case .Type = msoTextBox > .Name = "myTextBox"" to change to the text box content instead of "myTextBox".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not focused enough. As an example, your code includes cases for pictures and groups, neither of which have text that can be used to rename them. Text boxes and placeholders can hold a lot of text, leading to ridiculously long names. An overview of what problem you're trying to solve would also help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply John.
What we have is a PPT that is exported from Google Slides, but all the shapes, text boxes, objects, etc are not in order and have names like this https://prnt.sc/skws7d.
We need to place them in a certain order, so, in order to identify where each one belongs without having to click on each text box, we would like to get some of the content as the object name (3 or 4 words should be enough). Does this explanation help?